# Writing LLVM int/string input

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to generate llvm-ir from AST.

For displaying the integer output I added,

```
Constant *CalleeF = TheModule->getOrInsertFunction("printf",FunctionType::get(IntegerType::getInt32Ty(Context), PointerType::get(Type::getInt8Ty(Context), 0), true);`
```

And while calling print function I wrote,

```
Value* PrintStmt::codegen(){
  Value* V,*val,*to_print;
  vector<Value *> ArgsV;
  for (unsigned int i = 0, e = outs.size(); i != e; ++i){
     to_print = outs[i]->codegen();
     if(outs[i]->type=="int"){
         val=Builder.CreateGlobalStringPtr("%d");
     }
  ArgsV.push_back(val);
  ArgsV.push_back(to_print);
  V =  Builder.CreateCall(CalleeF, ArgsV, "printfCall");
 }
 return V;
}
```

What similar code should I write for getting input from user, i.e for scanf call?

Comment: i usually use clang for basic c->llvm ir conversion with flag "clang -emit-llvm test.c". it converts to scanf C to llvm ir "declare i32 @__isoc99_scanf(i8*, ...)"

Comment: @lazyCoder thanks, But my aim is to right code generator for scanf call. How can I do that after knowing the llvm-ir?

Answer (score 0):

For a `scanf` call you could first declare its prototype

```
llvm::FunctionType *readFnType = llvm::FunctionType::get(builder.getInt32Ty(), true); 
llvm::Function* readfn = llvm::Function::Create(readFnType, llvm::GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage, "scanf", TheModule));
```

And call it like so

```
std::vector<Value*> ArgsV; // holds codegen IR for each argument
std::string StringFormat; // holds string formatting for all arguments
for(auto& arg : Args){
        if(auto v = arg->codegen()){ 
            if(v->getType()->isDoubleTy())
                StringFormat += "%lf "; // 
            else if(v->getType()->isIntegerTy())
                StringFormat += "%d ";
            ArgsV.push_back(symbolTable[arg.name]);
        }else return nullptr;
    }
ArgsV.insert(ArgsV.begin(), builder.CreateGlobalStringPtr(StringFormat));
return builder.CreateCall(TheModule->getFunction("scanf"), ArgsV, "scanfCall");
```

Where `symbolTable` is a map of variable/argument names to a `Value*` holding the variable's stack allocated address. Recall that `scanf` takes the *address of the variable to be written to*, which explains the symbol table lookup.

It is also worth mentioning that this makes `scanf` inherently unsafe. You should consider using the `fgets` and `gets` functions instead.